# How do I compare the day of the week?

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I'm trying write a script which shows right statement based on which day of the week it is. Two examples:

1. If today is 4th day of the week. `echo Today is a working day.`
2. If today is 6th day of the week. `echo Today is a weekend.`

I wrote this however it doesn't work

```
echo Hello!
echo Today's date is: date
DAY=$(date +"%u")
if [ "${DZIEN}" -ge 1 && "${DZIEN}" -le 5 ]
then 
   echo WORKING DAY;
else
   echo WEEKEND;
fi
```

Comment: you set DAY, then check DZIEN... pick one. And perhaps try `-a` instead `&&`.

Comment: You need `[..] && [..]` or `[[.. && ..]]` - why don't you google for _shell multiple conditions in if_ ?? It's much shorter to type than all the above...

Comment: @frostschutz I made a mistake in copying variable name.

Comment: @don_crissti I have to do this in that way, this is a task from the teacher :/ Thanks for help, now it's working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
echo "Today's date is: $(date)"
day=$(date +"%u")

if ((day > 5)); then
   echo "WEEKEND"        
else
   echo "WORKING DAY"
fi
```

I use `(( ))` bash arithmetic

Or less readable :

```
echo "Today's date is: $(date)"
day=$(date +"%u")

if [[ day -gt 5 ]]; then
   echo "WEEKEND"        
else
   echo "WORKING DAY"
fi
```

Comment: Why does this work? What is `%u`?

Comment: From `man date`, % is the format specifier for day of week: `%u     day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday`